# How to Link Directly to a Parallax Scrolling Website Section

Tags: parallax, scroller

I'm building a parallax scroller that includes links to normal (non-parallax) pages on the navbar as well. This works fine when you're in the standard parallax scrolling section, but I cannot get a link from one of the other non-parallax pages to go directly to a section in the parallax site.

Links within the parallax look like this:
`<li><a href="#random-section">Things</a></li>`

I want to link to the *.html and then a specific section as well. Any ideas on how this could be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation is to do *.html#random-section, but you have probably already tried this.

My next recommendation is to go to the page first and use a GET value to tell your page what section to go to after the page has loaded. For example

```
*.html?section=randomSection
```

Then, you could use javascript to scroll to that section using

```
window.location.hash = "randomSection"
```

Your code could look something like this (assuming you are using PHP):

```
<head>
<script>
function goToHash(section)
{
    window.location.hash = section;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="goToHash(<?PHP echo "$_GET[\"section\"]";?>);">
```

This should tell your page to scroll to the desired section.  Sorry for the messy formatting.

EDIT: if you are using PHP, please don't forget to escape all inputs

```
mysqli_escape_string(
```

If you need more parallax tutorials, my company and I created a list at http://potentpages.com/parallax-tutorials